# Search XML with xpath with pipe symbol |

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath

I have an XML-Document and would like to find all nodes with either attribute="A" or attribute="B".

I have something like this, with an xpath query, that works when used in the oxygen XML editor:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('xml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for text in root.findall('.//node1/node2|//node3[node2[@attribute="A"]|node2[@attribute="B"]]/node2'):
        #get text.text 
        #do something
```

The should stay in the original order.
How can I do this in python 3?

Comment: Can you provide example of your xml and which nodes you expect to query?

Comment: I can't provide an example, because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to. The document has been generated automatically by abbyy finereader.

Comment: You can change the sensitive parts without chqnging the whole idea.

Answer (score 0):

ElementTree XML API provides [limited support of XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). You should be better using [`lxml` module](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/)